# Square LP. Consider the LP with $A$ square and nonsingular. Minimize $c^Tx$.

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

> Square LP. Consider the LP
> $$\text{minimize }c^Tx\\
> \text{subject to } Ax \le b$$
> with $A$ square and nonsingular. Show that the optimal value is given by
> $p^* = c^TA^{-1}b$ if $A^{-1}c \le 0$, and $p^{*} = -\infty$ otherwise.

In the solution the problem is transformed to $$\text{minimize }c^TA^{-1}y\\
\text{subject to } y \le b$$

by the change of variables $y=Ax$. Then, it says if $A^{-T}c \le 0$  the optimal solution is $y = b$, with $p^* = c^TA^{-1}b$. Otherwise, the LP is unbounded below.

The question is how the condition $A^{-1}c \le 0$ was derived (I don't understand the underlying logic)? Even if that condition is satisfied why does it imply that the optimal solution is $y = b$, with $p^* = c^TA^{-1}b$?

Comment: you mix up $A^{-1}c$ and $A^{-T}c$, is that intentional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $d=A^{-T}c$, then your objective function is now

$$\min d^Ty=\sum_{i=1}^ n d_i y_i$$

subject to $$y \le b$$

If one of the term $d_i > 0$, we can set $y_i \to -\infty$ while fixing the other $y_j$ and the overall objective function will go to $-\infty$.

If each of the term $d_i \le 0$, then we would want $y_i$ to be as large as possible to reduce the quantity.